# How do I get the output of a square-wave input? (singularity problem)

Tags: physics, singularity

I am trying to get the electrical response of a system to an input square wave. Here is the code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Rf = 10^7;
A = 10000;
\[Omega]pd = 2 Pi 100;
\[Omega]gbp = A \[Omega]pd;
\[Tau] = 1/\[Omega]pd;
Cj = 10^-12;
Cf = 10^-12;
H[s_] = A/(A + (Cf + Cj) Rf \[Tau] s^2 + s (A Cf Rf + Cj Rf + \[Tau]));

BodePlot[TransferFunctionModel[H[s], s]];

T = 2*10^-5;
TMAX = 4*10^-5;

in = OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[1, s], SquareWave[t/T], {t, 0, TMAX}];
out = OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[H[s], s], SquareWave[t/T], {t, 0, TMAX}];
Plot[{in, out}, {t, 0, TMAX}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}]
```

This works well, but if I put

```
Rf = 10^6
```

instead of

```
Rf = 10^7
```

I get this error:

> At t == 9.999999999999726`*^-6, step size is effectively zero; \ singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You post this question in the WOLFRAM Community; I will delete my answer.